# MySQL Workbench Export Privileges

Tags: mysql, database, export, mysql-workbench, privileges

Using MySQL Workbench 6.3, Windows Server 2012 R2.

I have created a user with SELECT privileges on a single database. This user is able to connect to the database and view the records in read only mode.

However I'd also like this user to be able to **export** the database, currently when they try (via manage > export data) the receive the following error.

```
'Access Denied for user 'user'@'xxx' (using password NO) when trying to connect'
```

Basically I only want this user to be able to read the database records and export the database.

Is it possible to add these additional privileges?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to grant 'LOCK TABLES' then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

if you can't change access, just check this checkbox.
[image]